# can't get key value from cookies though it was exist but invalid format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser, angular-cookies, cookiestore

I am setting some key in $cookieStore like `$cookieStore.put('temp',temp);` 
and saved ok in cookies but some where some bites of key value are changed ,

so when `$cookieStore.get('temp');` I get this error :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
>
> ```
> at Object.parse (<anonymous>)
> at Object.vc [as fromJson] (1.4.9_angular.min.js:15)
> at Object.getObject (1.4.9_angular-cookies.min.js:12)
> at Object.get (1.4.9_angular-cookies.min.js:13)
> ```

Please I need to know which can change the format of the value 
that cause the error when trying to get key value!

Comment: Would you mind creating a demo on https://plnkr.co/edit to replicate this. also, its better to debug code with `angular-cookies.js` rather than using `angular-cookies.min.js` . The `min` files do not give proper readable messages

Comment: @ShashankVivek , actually temp value is ``MDYwNzg4YWUtNjUzOC00NzYwLWI5MjItYzE4Y2E3ZDU0MDM5FvI4mk0s10gE+y0A`` and after calling ``$cookieStore.put('temp',temp);`` it became ``%22MDYwNzg4YWUtNjUzOC00NzYwLWI5MjItYzE4Y2E3ZDU0MDM5FvI4mk0s10gE%2By0A%22`` in browse cookies and this valid when trying to get , the issue occur when became like this ``MDYwNzg4YWUtNjUzOC00NzYwLWI5MjItYzE4Y2E3ZDU0MDM5FvI4mk0s10gE%2By0A`` and trying to get ``$cookieStore.get('temp');`` I am n't overriding it

Comment: Can you replicate this in https://plnkr.co/edit/5CV1I1dXSVA1hJxkgxsm?p=preview